# What was Nolan Sorrento’s password?

Tags: ready-player-one-2018

In the film *Ready Player One*, we catch a glimpse of Nolan Sorrento’s password written on a sticky note stuck to his chair. Later, we see Wade use this password to hack into Sorrento’s system.

The password is shown on-screen a few times, but I wasn’t able to catch it on my first watch.

What was Nolan Sorrento’s password?

Comment: If it wasn't "god" then he wasn't being true to the '80s.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The password is:

## B055man69

That is a zero and not a capital O as is evidenced by it having a slash through it.

[image: Post-it note showing the password]

Comment: In the Spanish dubbing of the movie the password is spelled as "Capital B, zero, five, five..."

Comment: @JohnP:  How do you know it wasn't Ø  or ∅ ?   Carefully when you cross mathematicians, or the Nordic.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Nolan Sorrento had his password written on a sticky note. I suspect he's probably not using Nordic symbols in his passwords.

Comment: It was definitely a 0, further when Wade gives it to Samantha verbally he calls out *"Capital B, zero, five, five, man, sixty-nine"* (source: myself -
saw it twice)

Comment: @StevenVascellaro:  Well, to pedantic about it:   He's a hacker.  Why **shouldn't** he use obscure characters as his own nerdy inclusion?   He would presumably know what characters he used.   The sticky is just a reminder.   In the present age of Unicode, I imagine there are people using strange mixes of international characters and emoji in their passwords.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Sorrento needed a pop culture research  team on call to hold a conversation. I assumed he had paid staff handle the hacking.